# Java: How to get a specific row by a given value?(.csv)

Tags: java, android, arrays, csv, row

Firstly, I don't want any of you to write the code for me. I do not want to be misunderstood. If you just want to give an example, that will be fine.

Let's think I have a csv data table(comma seperated) like:

```
>Temp     Press      Vf       Vg      Uf      Ug

>50       140        0,5      2,5     1,7     2,6

>60       145        0,502    2,6     1,8     2,68
```

It will continue for let's say 10 columns and 200 rows. How can I store values of a row column by column?
To illustrate I want to get the row which has 60 degree celcius. The other values find by the program and recorded like `p1=145, vf1=0.502, Vg1=2.6, Uf1=1.8 ...` Note: It is not only for "temp". Maybe the known value is a "Vf" in other case.

I have been searching for 3 days yet I couldn't find the exact same thing that I want. There was always something missing.

Comment: Are you parsing CSV with your own java program or using any API for the same ?

Comment: I don't use an API. Actually I need some directions to follow. :/

Comment: Is it normal that you use comma as a decimal separator?

Comment: My advice would be to use APIs for parsing the CSV which gives you the list of POJOs and then you can also perform any operations or get any number of row you want

Comment: Mmm, if you meant the table, yeah I get this data from a book. Commas are used in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BhavikAmbani ! I will research how to.

Comment: You can use beanid API for the same, which is currently I am using, you can get more reference from http://beanio.org/

Comment: OK! Im on it. Hope this will make everything easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using any API.

Create a class which represents one entry of the CSV file:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int temp;
    [...]

    public static MyClass createFromCsvEntry(String csvLine) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Parse the data of the CSV file and add the single entries to a list. You now can perform the search on these entries:

```
public class MyClassDao {

    private List<MyClass> data;

    [...] // parsing CSV file and add the entries to data list

    public List<MyClass> searchByTemp(int temp) {
         List<MyClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
         for (MyClass mc : data) {
             if (mc.getTemp().equals(temp)) {
                  result.add(mc);
             }
         }
         return result;
    }

    public List<MyClass> searchByAnyOtherValue(...) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Of course if there are other non-functional requirements, such as performance etc., this solution may be not the right choice.